# Qual o melhor jeito de inserir com SQL?

Tags: sql

Digo isso porque tem dois jeitos, pelo que entendi.

Tem o:

```
INSERT INTO teste SET nome = "Lucas", sobrenome = "Alves";
```

E também o jeito:

```
INSERT INTO teste (nome, sobrenome) VALUES ("Lucas", "Alves");
```

Questão de velocidade, de boas práticas, etc, tem alguma coisa a ver, ou é tudo a mesma coisa?

Comment: INSERT com SET eu não conhecia.

Comment: Também não, Dvdsamm, mas eu vi no curso do Bonieky ele usando, e funciona do mesmo jeito, ai fiquei na dúvida.

Comment: Maior legal isso. Com SET é bem melhor. Nesse site o cara até recomenda usar essa sintaxe https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2913-using-the-insert-into-set-syntax-in-mysql.htm

Comment: Achei melhor também, na hora da manutenção, fica mais fácil. Mas pelo que eu entendi, so funciona no MySQL e derivados, ai se precisar migrar pra outro banco de dados num futuro, ai tem que atualizar tudo,

Comment: A sintaxe fica igual a do UPDATE. Facilita bastante.

Comment: Cara, tenho uma herança "maldita" (coloquei entre aspas pra não parecer ingrato, mas sou muito grato. É só uma representação)... aprendi SQL com um amigo e peguei o padrão dele e nunca fui muito a fundo pra saber as variações. Pra mim era só aquilo que aprendi dele. :)

Comment: Eu faço curso na Upinside e com Bonieky, os dois são feras, cada um tem uma didática diferente, ai, um complementa o outro, to aprendendo bem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A primeira forma funciona no MySQL e derivados, mas não nos demais bancos de dados.

A segunda forma é a forma padrão que deve funcionar em todos os bancos de dados.

[**Veja aqui no SQLFiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/02731)

Comment: Ahhh, agora entendi. Poderia explicar derivados? Seria por exemplo, MySQL, ai funcionaria no MariaDB, etc...

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Exatamente.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado Victor!

Comment: @LucasCarvalho e para responder a segunda parte, a velocidade provavelmente é idêntica, pois os comando são processados mas não afetam o comportamento da execução, claro que só quem pode afirmar é quem conhece o nucleo do código, mas mesmo que haja uma diferença de velocidade deve ser de 0.000001 segundos :P

Comment: Realmente, se testar em `PostgreSQL 9.6` ele retorna erro: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "SET"`